# Paypal: L_ERRORCODE0:10401 Order total is invalid and invalid argument

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout, paypal-nvp

I followed https://www.paypal-labs.com/integrationwizard/ecpaypal/main.php to implement paypal sandbox account in my application. My code is spanned in 3 jsp  pages such as index.jsp -> expresscheckout.jsp -> paypalfunctions.jsp .

expresscheckout.jsp

```
<%@ include file="paypalfunctions.jsp"%>
<%
    String paymentAmount = "25";

    String currencyCodeType = "USD";
    String paymentType = "Sale";



    String returnURL = "http://2.appid.appspot.com/sucess.jsp";

    String cancelURL = "http://2.appid.appspot.com/canceled.jsp";


    HashMap nvp = CallShortcutExpressCheckout(paymentAmount,
            currencyCodeType, paymentType, returnURL, cancelURL,
            session);
    String strAck = nvp.get("ACK").toString();
    if (strAck != null && strAck.equalsIgnoreCase("Success")) {
        //' Redirect to paypal.com
        RedirectURL(nvp.get("TOKEN").toString(), response);
    } else {


        String ErrorCode = nvp.get("L_ERRORCODE0").toString();
        String ErrorShortMsg = nvp.get("L_SHORTMESSAGE0").toString();
        String ErrorLongMsg = nvp.get("L_LONGMESSAGE0").toString();
        String ErrorSeverityCode = nvp.get("L_SEVERITYCODE0")
                .toString();
    }
%>
```

paypalfunctions.jsp is follows :

```
<%

    gv_APIUserName  = "myid_78955666_biz_api1.gmail.com";
    gv_APIPassword  = "1347856389";
    gv_APISignature = "AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AuP4KrN6UABOJ1fGdNRYoIpc.qjr";

    //BN Code is only applicable for partners
    gv_BNCode       = "PP-ECWizard"; 

    boolean bSandbox = true;



    if (bSandbox == true)
    {
        gv_APIEndpoint = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp";
        PAYPAL_URL = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=";
    }
    else
    {
        gv_APIEndpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
        PAYPAL_URL = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=";
    } 

    String HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_SERVER = "";
    String HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_PORT = "";
    boolean USE_PROXY = false;

    gv_Version  = "2.3";

    //WinObjHttp Request proxy settings.
    gv_ProxyServer  = HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_SERVER;
    gv_ProxyServerPort = HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_PORT;
    gv_Proxy        = 2;    //'setting for proxy activation
    gv_UseProxy     = USE_PROXY;


%>

<%!

    String gv_APIEndpoint;
    String gv_APIUserName;
    String gv_APIPassword;
    String gv_APISignature;
    String gv_BNCode;

    String gv_Version;
    String gv_nvpHeader;
    String gv_ProxyServer;  
    String gv_ProxyServerPort; 
    int gv_Proxy;
    boolean gv_UseProxy;
    String PAYPAL_URL;

    public HashMap CallShortcutExpressCheckout( String paymentAmount, String currencyCodeType, String paymentType, 
                                                String returnURL, String cancelURL,
                                                HttpSession session)
    {

        session.setAttribute("paymentType", paymentType);
        session.setAttribute("currencyCodeType", currencyCodeType);
ored in $nvpstr
        */
        String nvpstr = "&Amt=25&PAYMENTACTION=" + paymentType + "&ReturnUrl=" + URLEncoder.encode( returnURL ) + "&CANCELURL=" + URLEncoder.encode( cancelURL ) + "&CURRENCYCODE=" + currencyCodeType;

        /* 
        Make the call to PayPal to get the Express Checkout token
        If the API call succeded, then redirect the buyer to PayPal
        to begin to authorize payment.  If an error occured, show the
        resulting errors
        */

        HashMap nvp = httpcall("SetExpressCheckout", nvpstr);
        String strAck = nvp.get("ACK").toString();
        session.setAttribute("nvpstr", nvpstr);
        session.setAttribute("strAck", strAck);
        if(strAck !=null && strAck.equalsIgnoreCase("Success"))
        {
            session.setAttribute("TOKEN", nvp.get("TOKEN").toString());
        }

        return nvp;
    }

    public HashMap CallMarkExpressCheckout( String paymentAmount, String currencyCodeType, String paymentType, String returnURL, 
                                String cancelURL, String shipToName, String shipToStreet, String shipToCity, String shipToState,
                                String shipToCountryCode, String shipToZip, String shipToStreet2, String phoneNum,
                                HttpSession session)
    {

        session.setAttribute("paymentType", paymentType);
        session.setAttribute("currencyCodeType", currencyCodeType);

        String nvpStr = "ADDROVERRIDE=1&Amt=" + paymentAmount + "&PAYMENTACTION=" + paymentType;
        nvpStr = nvpStr + "&CURRENCYCODE=" + currencyCodeType + "&ReturnUrl=" + URLEncoder.encode( returnURL ) + "&CANCELURL=" + URLEncoder.encode( cancelURL );
        nvpStr = nvpStr + "&SHIPTONAME=" + shipToName + "&SHIPTOSTREET=" + shipToStreet + "&SHIPTOSTREET2=" + shipToStreet2;
        nvpStr = nvpStr + "&SHIPTOCITY=" + shipToCity + "&SHIPTOSTATE=" + shipToState + "&SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE=" + shipToCountryCode;
        nvpStr = nvpStr + "&SHIPTOZIP=" + shipToZip + "&PHONENUM" + phoneNum;


        HashMap nvp = httpcall("SetExpressCheckout", nvpStr);//made a change from original code
        String strAck = nvp.get("ACK").toString();
        if(strAck !=null && (strAck.equalsIgnoreCase("Success") || strAck.equalsIgnoreCase("SuccessWithWarning")))
        {
            session.setAttribute("TOKEN", nvp.get("TOKEN").toString());
        }           
        return nvp;
    }

    public HashMap GetShippingDetails( String token, HttpSession session)
    {


        String nvpstr= "&TOKEN=" + token;


        HashMap nvp = httpcall("GetExpressCheckoutDetails", nvpstr);
        String strAck = nvp.get("ACK").toString();
        if(strAck !=null && (strAck.equalsIgnoreCase("Success") || strAck.equalsIgnoreCase("SuccessWithWarning")))
        {
            session.setAttribute("PAYERID", nvp.get("PAYERID").toString());
        }           
        return nvp;
    }

    public HashMap ConfirmPayment( String finalPaymentAmount, HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request)
    {

        String token            =  session.getAttribute("TOKEN").toString();
        String currencyCodeType =  session.getAttribute("currencyCodeType").toString();
        String paymentType      =  session.getAttribute("paymentType").toString();
        String payerID          =  session.getAttribute("PAYERID").toString();
        String serverName       =  request.getServerName();

        String nvpstr  = "&TOKEN=" + token + "&PAYERID=" + payerID + "&PAYMENTACTION=" + paymentType + "&AMT=" + finalPaymentAmount;
        nvpstr = nvpstr + "&CURRENCYCODE=" + currencyCodeType + "&IPADDRESS=" + serverName;

        HashMap nvp = httpcall("DoExpressCheckoutPayment", nvpstr);

        return nvp;
    }


    HashMap DirectPayment ( String paymentType, String paymentAmount,
                        String creditCardType, String creditCardNumber, String expDate, String cvv2,
                        String firstName, String lastName, String street, String city, String state, String zip, String countryCode,
                        String currencyCode, String IPAddress)
    {
        String nvpStr = "Amt=" + paymentAmount + "&PAYMENTACTION=" + paymentType;
        nvpStr += "&IPADDRESS=" + IPAddress;
        nvpStr += "&CREDITCARDTYPE=" + creditCardType + "&ACCT=" + creditCardNumber + "&EXPDATE=" + expDate + "&CVV2=" + cvv2;
        nvpStr += "&FIRSTNAME=" + firstName + "&LASTNAME=" + lastName + "&STREET=" + street + "&CITY=" + city + "&STATE=" + state + "&COUNTRYCODE=" + countryCode + "&ZIP=" + zip;
        nvpStr += "&CURRENCYCODE=" + currencyCode;

        return httpcall("DoDirectPayment", nvpStr);
    }

    public HashMap httpcall( String methodName, String nvpStr)
    {

        String version = "2.3";
        String agent = "Mozilla/4.0";
        String respText = "";
        HashMap nvp=null;


        String encodedData = "METHOD=" + methodName + "&VERSION=" + gv_Version + "&PWD=" + gv_APIPassword + "&USER=" + gv_APIUserName + "&SIGNATURE=" + gv_APISignature + nvpStr + "&BUTTONSOURCE=" + gv_BNCode;

        try 
        {
            URL postURL = new URL( gv_APIEndpoint );
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)postURL.openConnection();

            // Set connection parameters. We need to perform input and output, 
            // so set both as true. 
            conn.setDoInput (true);
            conn.setDoOutput (true);

            // Set the content type we are POSTing. We impersonate it as 
            // encoded form data 
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setRequestProperty( "User-Agent", agent );

            //conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", type );
            conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", String.valueOf( encodedData.length()) );
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            // get the output stream to POST to. 
            DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream());
            output.writeBytes( encodedData );
            output.flush();
            output.close ();

            // Read input from the input stream.
            DataInputStream  in = new DataInputStream (conn.getInputStream()); 
            int rc = conn.getResponseCode();
            if ( rc != -1)
            {
                BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( conn.getInputStream()));
                String _line = null;
                while(((_line = is.readLine()) !=null))
                {
                    respText = respText + _line;
                }           
                nvp = deformatNVP( respText );
            }
            return nvp;
        }
        catch( IOException e )
        {
            // handle the error here
            return null;
        }
    }

    public HashMap deformatNVP( String pPayload )
    {
        HashMap nvp = new HashMap(); 
        StringTokenizer stTok = new StringTokenizer( pPayload, "&");
        while (stTok.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            StringTokenizer stInternalTokenizer = new StringTokenizer( stTok.nextToken(), "=");
            if (stInternalTokenizer.countTokens() == 2)
            {
                String key = URLDecoder.decode( stInternalTokenizer.nextToken());
                String value = URLDecoder.decode( stInternalTokenizer.nextToken());
                nvp.put( key.toUpperCase(), value );
            }
        }
        return nvp;
    }

    public void RedirectURL( String token, HttpServletResponse response )
    {
        String payPalURL = PAYPAL_URL + token; 

        //response.sendRedirect( payPalURL );
        response.setStatus(302);
        response.setHeader( "Location", payPalURL );
        response.setHeader( "Connection", "close" );
    }
```

%>

When i click on express checkout it redirect to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-9CY1483461514290L .
But in 'Your order summary' , there is not showing current purchase amount.
Also after login with my buyer account and confirm the address and payment, following error messages show in my success.jsp page:

**TIMESTAMP:2012-09-18T06:07:32Z
CORRELATIONID:b4fe3695b410a
ACK:Failure
VERSION:84.0
BUILD:3622349
L_ERRORCODE0:10401
L_SHORTMESSAGE0:Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.
L_LONGMESSAGE0:Order total is invalid.
L_SEVERITYCODE0:Error**

But when i printed my name-value-pair(nvp), it contains the amount

**NVPSTR===>&Amt=25&PAYMENTACTION=Sale&ReturnUrl=http%3A%2F%2F2.appid.appspot.com%2Fsucess.jsp&CANCELURL=http%3A%2F%2F2.appid.appspot.com%2Fcanceled.jsp&CURRENCYCODE=USD**

Please solve or suggest a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to submit the amount in your DoExpressCheckoutPayment API call as well as your SetExpressCheckout API call. Currently, you are not submitting the amount for both your SetEC and DoEC, only for your SetEC. (if you didn't set it for SetEC you would never have gotten a token.)

Your DoEC call should be pretty much the same as your SetEC call except you don't need RETURNURL and CANCELURL.

Also, the amount will not show under order summary unless you submit the line item details for your transaction:

```
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Books 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=154.00 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=ABC123 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=2 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1=CDs 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1=50.00 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER1=BY-Z4736 
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1=3 
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=458.00 
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=20.00 
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=46.20 
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=524.20
```